# Rails 4 Passing an array of keys to exclude

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, hash

I am currently passing an array of keys to be excluded , using the standard * method ...

```
params_to_scrub = ["created_at", "encrypted_password"]
@rows << user.attributes.except(*params_to_scrub)
```

Is there any way to move it into the user object and call it  ?

```
@rows << user.attributes.except(user.params_to_exclude)
```

#  in the User AR class

```
 def params_to_exclude
   params_to_scrub = ["created_at", "encrypted_password"]
   return *params_to_scrub
 end
```

this does(t work ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make it a class method by adding self:

```
 def self.params_to_exclude
   params_to_scrub = ["created_at", "encrypted_password"]
 end
```

And call it like this:

```
@rows << user.attributes.except(*User.params_to_exclude)
```

Comment: removed the return, since that's not necesarry in Ruby!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
@rows << user.attributes.except("created_at", "encrypted_password")
```

Comment: thanks .. but this is what I want to avoid by placing the list of keys inside the AR class...